# udev .rules not running script

Tags: arch-linux, udev

I'd like my computer to run certain scripts when a specific keyboard is (1) plugged in, (2) plugged out, (3) detected at startup.

Here's the device:

```
[rob@X200 vim]$ lsusb | grep keyb
Bus 005 Device 012: ID 04d9:1400 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. PS/2 keyboard + mouse controller
```

and here's the .rules file:

```
[rob@X200 rules.d]$ cat 080-model-m.rules 
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04d9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1400", RUN+="/home/rob/home/scripts/caps-equals-super.sh"

ACTION=="remove", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04d9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1400", RUN+="/home/rob/home/scripts/revert-keyboard-to-default.sh"
```

**The scripts have been tested to work, but are not triggered upon device plugin/plugout.** I'm not quite sure how I'd go about having the script triggered if the keyboard is detected at startup, but I imagine I have to tell something (systemd, udev?) not to run the script until certain resources are ready.

Here's `udevadm monitor -p` on device plugin:

`KERNEL[78150.293418] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1 (usb)
ACTION=add
BUSNUM=005
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/005/014
DEVNUM=014
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1
DEVTYPE=usb_device
MAJOR=189
MINOR=525
PRODUCT=4d9/1400/143
SEQNUM=2260
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0`

KERNEL[78150.297188] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0 (usb)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
INTERFACE=3/1/1
MODALIAS=usb:v04D9p1400d0143dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc01ip01in00
PRODUCT=4d9/1400/143
SEQNUM=2261
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0

KERNEL[78150.315292] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0025 (hid)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0025
HID_ID=0003:000004D9:00001400
HID_NAME=HID 04d9:1400
HID_PHYS=usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input0
MODALIAS=hid:b0003g0001v000004D9p00001400
SEQNUM=2262
SUBSYSTEM=hid

KERNEL[78150.315615] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0025/input/input44 (input)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0025/input/input44
EV=120013
KEY=1000000000007 ff9f207ac14057ff febeffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
LED=7
MODALIAS=input:b0003v04D9p1400e0110-e0,1,4,11,14,k71,72,73,74,75,77,79,7A,7B,7C,7D,7E,7F,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,8A,8C,8E,96,98,9E,9F,A1,A3,A4,A5,A6,AD,B0,B1,B2,B3,B4,B7,B8,B9,BA,BB,BC,BD,BE,BF,C0,C1,C2,F0,ram4,l0,1,2,sfw
MSC=10
NAME="HID 04d9:1400"
PHYS="usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input0"
PRODUCT=3/4d9/1400/110
PROP=0
SEQNUM=2263
SUBSYSTEM=input
UNIQ=""

KERNEL[78150.315762] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0025/input/input44/event6 (input)
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=/dev/input/event6
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0025/input/input44/event6
MAJOR=13
MINOR=70
SEQNUM=2264
SUBSYSTEM=input

KERNEL[78150.315864] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0025/hidraw/hidraw0 (hidraw)
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=/dev/hidraw0
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0025/hidraw/hidraw0
MAJOR=247
MINOR=0
SEQNUM=2265
SUBSYSTEM=hidraw

KERNEL[78150.315934] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1 (usb)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
INTERFACE=3/1/2
MODALIAS=usb:v04D9p1400d0143dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc01ip02in01
PRODUCT=4d9/1400/143
SEQNUM=2266
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0

KERNEL[78150.348378] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0026 (hid)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0026
HID_ID=0003:000004D9:00001400
HID_NAME=HID 04d9:1400
HID_PHYS=usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input1
MODALIAS=hid:b0003g0001v000004D9p00001400
SEQNUM=2267
SUBSYSTEM=hid

KERNEL[78150.348750] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0026/input/input45 (input)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0026/input/input45
EV=17
KEY=1f0000 2000000 39fad941d001 1e000000000000 0
MODALIAS=input:b0003v04D9p1400e0110-e0,1,2,4,k71,72,73,74,80,8C,8E,8F,90,96,98,9B,9C,9E,9F,A1,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,AB,AC,AD,D9,110,111,112,113,114,r0,1,8,am4,lsfw
MSC=10
NAME="HID 04d9:1400"
PHYS="usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input1"
PRODUCT=3/4d9/1400/110
PROP=0
REL=103
SEQNUM=2268
SUBSYSTEM=input
UNIQ=""

KERNEL[78150.348806] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0026/input/input45/event7 (input)
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=/dev/input/event7
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0026/input/input45/event7
MAJOR=13
MINOR=71
SEQNUM=2269
SUBSYSTEM=input

KERNEL[78150.349215] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0026/input/input45/mouse0 (input)
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=/dev/input/mouse0
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0026/input/input45/mouse0
MAJOR=13
MINOR=32
SEQNUM=2270
SUBSYSTEM=input

KERNEL[78150.349570] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0026/hidraw/hidraw1 (hidraw)
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=/dev/hidraw1
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0026/hidraw/hidraw1
MAJOR=247
MINOR=1
SEQNUM=2271
SUBSYSTEM=hidraw

UDEV  [78150.352414] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1 (usb)
ACTION=add
BUSNUM=005
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/005/014
DEVNUM=014
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1
DEVTYPE=usb_device
ID_BUS=usb
ID_MODEL=1400
ID_MODEL_ENC=1400
ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=PS/2 keyboard + mouse controller
ID_MODEL_ID=1400
ID_REVISION=0143
ID_SERIAL=04d9_1400
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030101:030102:
ID_VENDOR=04d9
ID_VENDOR_ENC=04d9
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Holtek Semiconductor, Inc.
ID_VENDOR_ID=04d9
MAJOR=189
MINOR=525
PRODUCT=4d9/1400/143
SEQNUM=2260
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
USEC_INITIALIZED=150293560

UDEV  [78150.359452] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0 (usb)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=PS/2 keyboard + mouse controller
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Holtek Semiconductor, Inc.
INTERFACE=3/1/1
MODALIAS=usb:v04D9p1400d0143dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc01ip01in00
PRODUCT=4d9/1400/143
SEQNUM=2261
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
USEC_INITIALIZED=297361

UDEV  [78150.361013] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0025 (hid)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0025
HID_ID=0003:000004D9:00001400
HID_NAME=HID 04d9:1400
HID_PHYS=usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input0
MODALIAS=hid:b0003g0001v000004D9p00001400
SEQNUM=2262
SUBSYSTEM=hid
USEC_INITIALIZED=315394

UDEV  [78150.363279] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0025/input/input44 (input)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0025/input/input44
EV=120013
ID_BUS=usb
ID_FOR_SEAT=input-pci-0000_00_1d_0-usb-0_1_1_0
ID_INPUT=1
ID_INPUT_KEY=1
ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD=1
ID_MODEL=1400
ID_MODEL_ENC=1400
ID_MODEL_ID=1400
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1:1.0
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_1d_0-usb-0_1_1_0
ID_REVISION=0143
ID_SERIAL=04d9_1400
ID_TYPE=hid
ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030101:030102:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
ID_VENDOR=04d9
ID_VENDOR_ENC=04d9
ID_VENDOR_ID=04d9
KEY=1000000000007 ff9f207ac14057ff febeffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
LED=7
MODALIAS=input:b0003v04D9p1400e0110-e0,1,4,11,14,k71,72,73,74,75,77,79,7A,7B,7C,7D,7E,7F,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,8A,8C,8E,96,98,9E,9F,A1,A3,A4,A5,A6,AD,B0,B1,B2,B3,B4,B7,B8,B9,BA,BB,BC,BD,BE,BF,C0,C1,C2,F0,ram4,l0,1,2,sfw
MSC=10
NAME="HID 04d9:1400"
PHYS="usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input0"
PRODUCT=3/4d9/1400/110
PROP=0
SEQNUM=2263
SUBSYSTEM=input
TAGS=:seat:
UNIQ=""
USEC_INITIALIZED=315688

UDEV  [78150.363612] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1 (usb)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=PS/2 keyboard + mouse controller
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Holtek Semiconductor, Inc.
INTERFACE=3/1/2
MODALIAS=usb:v04D9p1400d0143dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc01ip02in01
PRODUCT=4d9/1400/143
SEQNUM=2266
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
USEC_INITIALIZED=150315976

UDEV  [78150.366574] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0025/hidraw/hidraw0 (hidraw)
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=/dev/hidraw0
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0025/hidraw/hidraw0
MAJOR=247
MINOR=0
SEQNUM=2265
SUBSYSTEM=hidraw
USEC_INITIALIZED=150315900

UDEV  [78150.367209] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0026 (hid)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0026
HID_ID=0003:000004D9:00001400
HID_NAME=HID 04d9:1400
HID_PHYS=usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input1
MODALIAS=hid:b0003g0001v000004D9p00001400
SEQNUM=2267
SUBSYSTEM=hid
USEC_INITIALIZED=348465

UDEV  [78150.369365] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0026/input/input45 (input)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0026/input/input45
EV=17
ID_BUS=usb
ID_FOR_SEAT=input-pci-0000_00_1d_0-usb-0_1_1_1
ID_INPUT=1
ID_INPUT_KEY=1
ID_INPUT_MOUSE=1
ID_MODEL=1400
ID_MODEL_ENC=1400
ID_MODEL_ID=1400
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1:1.1
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_1d_0-usb-0_1_1_1
ID_REVISION=0143
ID_SERIAL=04d9_1400
ID_TYPE=hid
ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030101:030102:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=01
ID_VENDOR=04d9
ID_VENDOR_ENC=04d9
ID_VENDOR_ID=04d9
KEY=1f0000 2000000 39fad941d001 1e000000000000 0
MODALIAS=input:b0003v04D9p1400e0110-e0,1,2,4,k71,72,73,74,80,8C,8E,8F,90,96,98,9B,9C,9E,9F,A1,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,AB,AC,AD,D9,110,111,112,113,114,r0,1,8,am4,lsfw
MSC=10
NAME="HID 04d9:1400"
PHYS="usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input1"
PRODUCT=3/4d9/1400/110
PROP=0
REL=103
SEQNUM=2268
SUBSYSTEM=input
TAGS=:seat:
UNIQ=""
USEC_INITIALIZED=349029

UDEV  [78150.370966] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0026/hidraw/hidraw1 (hidraw)
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=/dev/hidraw1
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0026/hidraw/hidraw1
MAJOR=247
MINOR=1
SEQNUM=2271
SUBSYSTEM=hidraw
USEC_INITIALIZED=349776

UDEV  [78150.372975] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0026/input/input45/event7 (input)
ACTION=add
DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-id/usb-04d9_1400-if01-event-mouse /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1:1.1-event-mouse
DEVNAME=/dev/input/event7
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0026/input/input45/event7
ID_BUS=usb
ID_INPUT=1
ID_INPUT_KEY=1
ID_INPUT_MOUSE=1
ID_MODEL=1400
ID_MODEL_ENC=1400
ID_MODEL_ID=1400
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1:1.1
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_1d_0-usb-0_1_1_1
ID_REVISION=0143
ID_SERIAL=04d9_1400
ID_TYPE=hid
ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030101:030102:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=01
ID_VENDOR=04d9
ID_VENDOR_ENC=04d9
ID_VENDOR_ID=04d9
MAJOR=13
MINOR=71
SEQNUM=2269
SUBSYSTEM=input
USEC_INITIALIZED=349103

UDEV  [78150.373507] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0025/input/input44/event6 (input)
ACTION=add
DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-id/usb-04d9_1400-event-kbd /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1:1.0-event-kbd
DEVNAME=/dev/input/event6
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0025/input/input44/event6
ID_BUS=usb
ID_INPUT=1
ID_INPUT_KEY=1
ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD=1
ID_MODEL=1400
ID_MODEL_ENC=1400
ID_MODEL_ID=1400
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1:1.0
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_1d_0-usb-0_1_1_0
ID_REVISION=0143
ID_SERIAL=04d9_1400
ID_TYPE=hid
ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030101:030102:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
ID_VENDOR=04d9
ID_VENDOR_ENC=04d9
ID_VENDOR_ID=04d9
MAJOR=13
MINOR=70
SEQNUM=2264
SUBSYSTEM=input
USEC_INITIALIZED=315738

UDEV  [78150.408756] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0026/input/input45/mouse0 (input)
ACTION=add
DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-id/usb-04d9_1400-if01-mouse /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1:1.1-mouse
DEVNAME=/dev/input/mouse0
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0026/input/input45/mouse0
ID_BUS=usb
ID_INPUT=1
ID_INPUT_KEY=1
ID_INPUT_MOUSE=1
ID_MODEL=1400
ID_MODEL_ENC=1400
ID_MODEL_ID=1400
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1:1.1
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_1d_0-usb-0_1_1_1
ID_REVISION=0143
ID_SERIAL=04d9_1400
ID_TYPE=hid
ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030101:030102:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=01
ID_VENDOR=04d9
ID_VENDOR_ENC=04d9
ID_VENDOR_ID=04d9
MAJOR=13
MINOR=32
SEQNUM=2270
SUBSYSTEM=input
USEC_INITIALIZED=150349156

and plugout:

`KERNEL[78050.382672] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0023/input/input42/event6 (input)
ACTION=remove
DEVNAME=/dev/input/event6
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0023/input/input42/event6
MAJOR=13
MINOR=70
SEQNUM=2248
SUBSYSTEM=input`

UDEV  [78050.385911] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0023/input/input42/event6 (input)
ACTION=remove
DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-id/usb-04d9_1400-event-kbd /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1:1.0-event-kbd
DEVNAME=/dev/input/event6
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0023/input/input42/event6
ID_BUS=usb
ID_INPUT=1
ID_INPUT_KEY=1
ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD=1
ID_MODEL=1400
ID_MODEL_ENC=1400
ID_MODEL_ID=1400
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1:1.0
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_1d_0-usb-0_1_1_0
ID_REVISION=0143
ID_SERIAL=04d9_1400
ID_TYPE=hid
ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030101:030102:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
ID_VENDOR=04d9
ID_VENDOR_ENC=04d9
ID_VENDOR_ID=04d9
MAJOR=13
MINOR=70
SEQNUM=2248
SUBSYSTEM=input
USEC_INITIALIZED=215964

KERNEL[78050.399307] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0023/input/input42 (input)
ACTION=remove
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0023/input/input42
EV=120013
KEY=1000000000007 ff9f207ac14057ff febeffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
LED=7
MODALIAS=input:b0003v04D9p1400e0110-e0,1,4,11,14,k71,72,73,74,75,77,79,7A,7B,7C,7D,7E,7F,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,8A,8C,8E,96,98,9E,9F,A1,A3,A4,A5,A6,AD,B0,B1,B2,B3,B4,B7,B8,B9,BA,BB,BC,BD,BE,BF,C0,C1,C2,F0,ram4,l0,1,2,sfw
MSC=10
NAME="HID 04d9:1400"
PHYS="usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input0"
PRODUCT=3/4d9/1400/110
PROP=0
SEQNUM=2249
SUBSYSTEM=input
UNIQ=""

KERNEL[78050.399658] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0023/hidraw/hidraw0 (hidraw)
ACTION=remove
DEVNAME=/dev/hidraw0
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0023/hidraw/hidraw0
MAJOR=247
MINOR=0
SEQNUM=2250
SUBSYSTEM=hidraw

KERNEL[78050.399744] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0023 (hid)
ACTION=remove
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0023
HID_ID=0003:000004D9:00001400
HID_NAME=HID 04d9:1400
HID_PHYS=usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input0
MODALIAS=hid:b0003g0001v000004D9p00001400
SEQNUM=2251
SUBSYSTEM=hid

KERNEL[78050.399821] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0 (usb)
ACTION=remove
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
INTERFACE=3/1/1
MODALIAS=usb:v04D9p1400d0143dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc01ip01in00
PRODUCT=4d9/1400/143
SEQNUM=2252
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0

UDEV  [78050.402035] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0023/input/input42 (input)
ACTION=remove
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0023/input/input42
EV=120013
ID_BUS=usb
ID_FOR_SEAT=input-pci-0000_00_1d_0-usb-0_1_1_0
ID_INPUT=1
ID_INPUT_KEY=1
ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD=1
ID_MODEL=1400
ID_MODEL_ENC=1400
ID_MODEL_ID=1400
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1:1.0
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_1d_0-usb-0_1_1_0
ID_REVISION=0143
ID_SERIAL=04d9_1400
ID_TYPE=hid
ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030101:030102:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
ID_VENDOR=04d9
ID_VENDOR_ENC=04d9
ID_VENDOR_ID=04d9
KEY=1000000000007 ff9f207ac14057ff febeffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
LED=7
MODALIAS=input:b0003v04D9p1400e0110-e0,1,4,11,14,k71,72,73,74,75,77,79,7A,7B,7C,7D,7E,7F,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,8A,8C,8E,96,98,9E,9F,A1,A3,A4,A5,A6,AD,B0,B1,B2,B3,B4,B7,B8,B9,BA,BB,BC,BD,BE,BF,C0,C1,C2,F0,ram4,l0,1,2,sfw
MSC=10
NAME="HID 04d9:1400"
PHYS="usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input0"
PRODUCT=3/4d9/1400/110
PROP=0
SEQNUM=2249
SUBSYSTEM=input
TAGS=:seat:
UNIQ=""
USEC_INITIALIZED=215881

UDEV  [78050.403745] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0023/hidraw/hidraw0 (hidraw)
ACTION=remove
DEVNAME=/dev/hidraw0
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0023/hidraw/hidraw0
MAJOR=247
MINOR=0
SEQNUM=2250
SUBSYSTEM=hidraw
USEC_INITIALIZED=50400126

UDEV  [78050.405656] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0023 (hid)
ACTION=remove
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:1400.0023
HID_ID=0003:000004D9:00001400
HID_NAME=HID 04d9:1400
HID_PHYS=usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input0
MODALIAS=hid:b0003g0001v000004D9p00001400
SEQNUM=2251
SUBSYSTEM=hid
USEC_INITIALIZED=400682

UDEV  [78050.407323] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0 (usb)
ACTION=remove
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=PS/2 keyboard + mouse controller
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Holtek Semiconductor, Inc.
INTERFACE=3/1/1
MODALIAS=usb:v04D9p1400d0143dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc01ip01in00
PRODUCT=4d9/1400/143
SEQNUM=2252
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
USEC_INITIALIZED=197298

KERNEL[78050.432446] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0024/input/input43/event7 (input)
ACTION=remove
DEVNAME=/dev/input/event7
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0024/input/input43/event7
MAJOR=13
MINOR=71
SEQNUM=2253
SUBSYSTEM=input

UDEV  [78050.434993] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0024/input/input43/event7 (input)
ACTION=remove
DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-id/usb-04d9_1400-if01-event-mouse /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1:1.1-event-mouse
DEVNAME=/dev/input/event7
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0024/input/input43/event7
ID_BUS=usb
ID_INPUT=1
ID_INPUT_KEY=1
ID_INPUT_MOUSE=1
ID_MODEL=1400
ID_MODEL_ENC=1400
ID_MODEL_ID=1400
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1:1.1
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_1d_0-usb-0_1_1_1
ID_REVISION=0143
ID_SERIAL=04d9_1400
ID_TYPE=hid
ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030101:030102:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=01
ID_VENDOR=04d9
ID_VENDOR_ENC=04d9
ID_VENDOR_ID=04d9
MAJOR=13
MINOR=71
SEQNUM=2253
SUBSYSTEM=input
USEC_INITIALIZED=248972

KERNEL[78050.456155] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0024/input/input43/mouse0 (input)
ACTION=remove
DEVNAME=/dev/input/mouse0
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0024/input/input43/mouse0
MAJOR=13
MINOR=32
SEQNUM=2254
SUBSYSTEM=input

UDEV  [78050.457413] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0024/input/input43/mouse0 (input)
ACTION=remove
DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-id/usb-04d9_1400-if01-mouse /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1:1.1-mouse
DEVNAME=/dev/input/mouse0
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0024/input/input43/mouse0
ID_BUS=usb
ID_INPUT=1
ID_INPUT_KEY=1
ID_INPUT_MOUSE=1
ID_MODEL=1400
ID_MODEL_ENC=1400
ID_MODEL_ID=1400
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1:1.1
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_1d_0-usb-0_1_1_1
ID_REVISION=0143
ID_SERIAL=04d9_1400
ID_TYPE=hid
ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030101:030102:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=01
ID_VENDOR=04d9
ID_VENDOR_ENC=04d9
ID_VENDOR_ID=04d9
MAJOR=13
MINOR=32
SEQNUM=2254
SUBSYSTEM=input
USEC_INITIALIZED=249005

KERNEL[78050.490161] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0024/input/input43 (input)
ACTION=remove
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0024/input/input43
EV=17
KEY=1f0000 2000000 39fad941d001 1e000000000000 0
MODALIAS=input:b0003v04D9p1400e0110-e0,1,2,4,k71,72,73,74,80,8C,8E,8F,90,96,98,9B,9C,9E,9F,A1,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,AB,AC,AD,D9,110,111,112,113,114,r0,1,8,am4,lsfw
MSC=10
NAME="HID 04d9:1400"
PHYS="usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input1"
PRODUCT=3/4d9/1400/110
PROP=0
REL=103
SEQNUM=2255
SUBSYSTEM=input
UNIQ=""

KERNEL[78050.490227] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0024/hidraw/hidraw1 (hidraw)
ACTION=remove
DEVNAME=/dev/hidraw1
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0024/hidraw/hidraw1
MAJOR=247
MINOR=1
SEQNUM=2256
SUBSYSTEM=hidraw

UDEV  [78050.490261] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0024/hidraw/hidraw1 (hidraw)
ACTION=remove
DEVNAME=/dev/hidraw1
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0024/hidraw/hidraw1
MAJOR=247
MINOR=1
SEQNUM=2256
SUBSYSTEM=hidraw
USEC_INITIALIZED=489761

KERNEL[78050.490301] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0024 (hid)
ACTION=remove
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0024
HID_ID=0003:000004D9:00001400
HID_NAME=HID 04d9:1400
HID_PHYS=usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input1
MODALIAS=hid:b0003g0001v000004D9p00001400
SEQNUM=2257
SUBSYSTEM=hid

KERNEL[78050.490340] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1 (usb)
ACTION=remove
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
INTERFACE=3/1/2
MODALIAS=usb:v04D9p1400d0143dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc01ip02in01
PRODUCT=4d9/1400/143
SEQNUM=2258
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0

UDEV  [78050.491393] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0024/input/input43 (input)
ACTION=remove
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0024/input/input43
EV=17
ID_BUS=usb
ID_FOR_SEAT=input-pci-0000_00_1d_0-usb-0_1_1_1
ID_INPUT=1
ID_INPUT_KEY=1
ID_INPUT_MOUSE=1
ID_MODEL=1400
ID_MODEL_ENC=1400
ID_MODEL_ID=1400
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1:1.1
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_1d_0-usb-0_1_1_1
ID_REVISION=0143
ID_SERIAL=04d9_1400
ID_TYPE=hid
ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030101:030102:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=01
ID_VENDOR=04d9
ID_VENDOR_ENC=04d9
ID_VENDOR_ID=04d9
KEY=1f0000 2000000 39fad941d001 1e000000000000 0
MODALIAS=input:b0003v04D9p1400e0110-e0,1,2,4,k71,72,73,74,80,8C,8E,8F,90,96,98,9B,9C,9E,9F,A1,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,AB,AC,AD,D9,110,111,112,113,114,r0,1,8,am4,lsfw
MSC=10
NAME="HID 04d9:1400"
PHYS="usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input1"
PRODUCT=3/4d9/1400/110
PROP=0
REL=103
SEQNUM=2255
SUBSYSTEM=input
TAGS=:seat:
UNIQ=""
USEC_INITIALIZED=248939

UDEV  [78050.491500] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0024 (hid)
ACTION=remove
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1400.0024
HID_ID=0003:000004D9:00001400
HID_NAME=HID 04d9:1400
HID_PHYS=usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input1
MODALIAS=hid:b0003g0001v000004D9p00001400
SEQNUM=2257
SUBSYSTEM=hid
USEC_INITIALIZED=489833

UDEV  [78050.491546] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1 (usb)
ACTION=remove
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=PS/2 keyboard + mouse controller
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Holtek Semiconductor, Inc.
INTERFACE=3/1/2
MODALIAS=usb:v04D9p1400d0143dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc01ip02in01
PRODUCT=4d9/1400/143
SEQNUM=2258
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
USEC_INITIALIZED=32216435

KERNEL[78050.509101] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1 (usb)
ACTION=remove
BUSNUM=005
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/005/013
DEVNUM=013
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1
DEVTYPE=usb_device
MAJOR=189
MINOR=524
PRODUCT=4d9/1400/143
SEQNUM=2259
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0

UDEV  [78050.509856] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1 (usb)
ACTION=remove
BUSNUM=005
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/005/013
DEVNUM=013
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1
DEVTYPE=usb_device
ID_BUS=usb
ID_MODEL=1400
ID_MODEL_ENC=1400
ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=PS/2 keyboard + mouse controller
ID_MODEL_ID=1400
ID_REVISION=0143
ID_SERIAL=04d9_1400
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030101:030102:
ID_VENDOR=04d9
ID_VENDOR_ENC=04d9
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Holtek Semiconductor, Inc.
ID_VENDOR_ID=04d9
MAJOR=189
MINOR=524
PRODUCT=4d9/1400/143
SEQNUM=2259
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
USEC_INITIALIZED=32193478

Comment: What does `udevadm monitor -p` show when you plug/unplug the keyboard?

Comment: Check your log (`journalctl -b`). You should have some errors like `failed to execute '/home/rob/home/scripts......sh' '/home/rob/home/scripts....sh': Exec format error`. If so, change the  values for the `RUN` keys in your udev rule like this: `RUN+="/usr/bin/sh -c '/home/rob/.......sh'"`. Note you have to use the full path for `sh` (you can get it with `whereis -b sh`).

Comment: Could you post the full setup (add used scripts)?

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, there could be two problems.

1. The scripts does not have 777 permissions.
2. The way you are invoking. Try as below. They should work.

The udev rule file

```
$ cat 080-model-m.rules 
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04d9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1400", RUN+="/bin/sh /home/rob/home/scripts/caps-equals-super.sh"

ACTION=="remove", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04d9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1400", RUN+="/bin/sh /home/rob/home/scripts/revert-keyboard-to-default.sh"
```

Note the `/bin/sh` in the beginnig of `RUN`. Also, cross check the path of the shell script once again.

Also once you made the changes to the udev rules, make sure to do `udevadm trigger` so that the udev rules are reloaded